# Python 2.5 to 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, upgrade, python-2.5

I have a computer with python 2.5
I have written a software that runs on python 2.5 (rather big, over 30k lines of code)

I am thinking about upgrading my computer to python 2.7 because i want to implement multithreading.
However, I have some concerns whether this would break my software or not.

Is there guidelines to make this transition smooth?
any tips?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python25/diff27

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a good use case for using a Python virtual environment to test your code, see the virtualenv :

http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/

You can use the `--python` flag to specify a Python version in your virtual environment:

```
virtualenv --python /path/to/python2.7 env_27
```